# RAM placement issue on R710

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell

I have 16GB RAMs, each 2GB. I don't know how to place them in order. Please help me out.
It shows error when I go to System Setup about DIMMs being incorrect.

Comment: On the back of the server cover you have a schematic which explains how to populate memory slots. Also, easy search found [official manual](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r710_owner's%20manual_en-us.pdf) about managing this server hardware. Did you read it and made everything according to the manual? So, add into the question: what exactly modules do you have? How exactly you populated slots? What is the error message (a screenshot or exact text)?

Comment: MEMBIST failure -  The following DIMM has been disabled by BIOS: DIMM

Comment: I don't understand the manual. It's too confusing for me. Sorry to bother yall.

Comment: @DissociatedFun, if you do not want to understand manual you may pay for Dell support to place the RAM.

Comment: My issue is I'm in a middle eastern country where Dell doesn't have support.

Comment: Check page 132 from manual. And with single processor you can have 12 or 18GB of RAM.

Comment: I have both CPUs can you tell me which location I need place them.

Comment: @DissociatedFun, are lazy? You have the image in front of you. Start thinking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138528/discussion-between-dissociatedfun-and-romeo-ninov).

Comment: The Dell manual isn't confusing at all and doesn't require any special knowledge. For this matter, it requires only the ability to compare things to pictures and ability to read labels and count; that is elementary school knowledge. If you are unable to understand it, find someone clever, pay them and they will do the work for you. Sorry.

Comment: Check for Dell R710 DIMM slots population videos and examples. There are plenty of those. The thing is that there are specific rules in populating RAM in a dual-socket system. Here's and example: https://cloudninjas.com/collections/poweredge-r710#:~:text=The%20R710%20is%20a%20Dual,two%20unbuffered%20DIMMs%20per%20channel.